# Large cardinals without replacement

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Let $ZC$ be [Zermelo set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory) with choice, which differs from $ZFC$ in omitting the axiom scheme of replacement. **EDIT:** I think I want to include foundation in the axioms, which apparently isn't normally considered to be part of Zermelo set theory.

As is well-known, $ZC$ is much weaker than $ZFC$; for instance $V_{\aleph_\omega}$ models $ZC$. One way to measure the difference is by interpolating between the two with the theories $ZC_n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$, where one adds an axiom or axiom scheme of $\Sigma_n$ replacement; I believe one has $ZC = ZC_0$ and informally $ZFC = ZC_\omega$. At the extreme low end, I believe that $ZC$ doesn't even prove that every well-order is isomorphic to an ordinal, so if it makes things easier in the following to replace $ZC$ with $ZC_1$, I don't think I'd object.

What I'd like to know is whether $ZC$ admits a "large cardinal hierarchy" resembling in some sense the familiar hierachy of large cardinal axioms one can add to $ZFC$, and which give another way of calibrating consistency strength of such theories.

When trying to adapt large-cardinal ideas from $ZFC$ to $ZC$, I imagine there are plenty of potential issues.

- For one thing, as usual equivalent formulations of a statement in $ZFC$ may become inequivalent in $ZC$, so one must think carefully about choosing "correct" formulations.
- More concerningly, the canonical example of a model of $ZC$ given by $V_{\aleph_\omega}$ suggests that perhaps one way $ZC$ differs from $ZFC$ is that in $ZC$ the universe *doesn't* necessarily "extend endlessly upward", and so "adding to the top" by hypothesizing "large cardinals" may simply be an ineffective way to generate stronger extensions of $ZC$ which are not extensions of $ZFC$.

So I think the somewhat-more-specific questions I have are:

**Question 1:** Is there anything analogous to the large cardinal hierarchy when it comes to theories which extend $ZC$ but not $ZFC$?

Or is it rather the case that anything recognizable as a "large cardinal axiom" in $ZC$ will likely imply replacement anyway?

**Question 2:** If so, does this hierarchy lie strictly below $ZFC$ in consistency strength?

Or is it rather possible to get a theory without replacement which is *stronger* than $ZFC$ in consistency strength, or even *incomparable*?

**Question 3:** What's an example of an analog of a large cardinal axiom in $ZC$? (Or if the answer to (1) is "no", then: what are some other interesting ways to get theories between $ZC$ and $ZFC$ other than the theories $ZC_n$?)

My favorite large cardinal axiom happens to be Vopenka's principle. So for instance, is there a version of Vopenka in $ZC$, and if so, is the resulting theory weaker than $ZFC$?

I'd also be interested in asking similar questions about $BZC$, the material-set-theoretic analog of ETCS, where the language is modified so that there simply aren't any unbounded quantifiers at all. But perhaps that would be too radically different a setting from $ZFC$ to really get a grip on the question.

Comment: This is probably not what you had in mind, but just in case: if we weaken ZC even more and restrict Separation to Δ₀ formulae, but add Δ₀ replacement, we get Kripke-Platek (KP) + powerset. Now KP has its own hierarchy of “recursively large ordinals” (recursively inaccessible, recursively Mahlo, nonprojectible, etc.), which reflect the “small” large cardinals. The theory Power-KP obtained by adding a powerset function (rather than axiom) to KP has been studied, and seems to have much in common with KP (its transitive models are called “power-admissible” sets). … (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) … So I am tempted to believe that there should be notions like “power-recursively inaccessible”, “power-recursively Mahlo”, etc., waiting to be studied. AFAICT this hasn't received any attention, but it could be an interesting hierarchy to look at.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thanks, that's good to know. As is probably apparent, I don't really know enough set theory to say with confidence that ZC is the base theory I'm "really" interested in. Just to be sure I have it straight, we have that ZC interprets KP+Powerset and KP+Powerset interprets BZC=Mac Lane, but between KP and Mac Lane neither one "directly" interprets the other, right?

Comment: I'm afraid I easily get lost in the twisty maze of theories all alike, but the reference here is [Mathias's paper “The Strength of Mac Lane Set Theory”](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007200000312). Let's just say I was mostly suggesting a look at the theory $\mathsf{KP}^{\mathcal{P}}$ (in the terminology of this paper), which is somewhat better behaved than $\mathsf{Z}$ and presumably admits an interesting hierarchy of “small large” cardinals (whose existence in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ would be probable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall, the large cardinal axiom hierarchy is very similar between ZC (ZFC minus replacement; we are including regularity) and ZFC.  A large cardinal axiom (unprovable in ZFC) satisfied by $κ$ typically implies in ZC that $V_κ$ satisfies ZFC + weaker large cardinal axioms.  However, the axioms typically do not imply additional replacement above $κ$ even for $Σ^V_3$ axioms such as existence of a strong or a supercompact cardinal (and hence their strength is truncated accordingly); but an extendible or a proper class of strong cardinals gives $Σ_2$ replacement, and a proper class of extendibles gives $Σ_3$ replacement.

Equiconsistencies also typically carry over to ZC.  For example, ZC + $L(ℝ)⊨\text{AD}$ is equiconsistent with ZC + $ω$ Woodin cardinals whose supremum exists.

However, there are some differences.

One is notational.  ZC does not prove that $ω2=ω+ω$ exists as the transitive set.  However, ZC interprets $Σ_1$ replacement, and we can either add $Σ_1$-replacement, or implicitly speak of codes for ordinals and other sets.

Defining HOD requires replacement.  However, there are inequivalent first order definable approximations of OD in ZC, one of which is $∪_{V_κ \text{ exists}} \mathrm{OD}^{V_κ}$.

The lack of singular infinite cardinals creates some strength differences.  For example, ZC + $∀κ \, (κ^+)^L < κ^+$ is equiconsistent with ZC rather than ZC + $0^\#$.  Still, there are other covering properties whose violation has high strength in ZC, and nonexistence of an inner model with a Woodin cardinal should still imply that the core model exists.  Also, ZC($j$) + “$j$ is a nontrivial elementary embedding $V→V$” (called Wholeness Axiom; it proves ZFC without replacement for $j$-formulas) is consistent relative to the $\mathrm{I}_3$ axiom, as opposed to the Kunen inconsistency in ZFC($j$) due to the axiom of choice and existence of $j^ω(\mathrm{crit}(j))$.

There are large cardinal axioms for ZC that are implied by ZFC.  Borel determinacy is equivalent to $∀r∈ℝ \,∀α < ω_1 \, ∃β \, L_β(r) ⊨  \text{“} ω_α \text{ exists”}$.  Also, the least $α<β$ with $\mathrm{Theory}(V_α)=\mathrm{Theory}(V_β)$ are strictly between $ω_1^L$ and $c^+$.

Bounded quantifier ZC (BZC, also called Mac Lane set theory) is useful for some equiconsistency statements, and as a minimal base theory.  For example, BZC + a proper class of Woodin cardinals is conservative over $\text{Z}_2 + \text{PD}$ (second order arithmetic with projective determinacy).  In turn, key theorems about universally Baire sets relying on a proper class of Woodin cardinals can in fact be proved in BZC + a proper class of Woodin cardinals (even though it does not prove that the set of all universally Baire sets of reals exists).

By reflection, for every consistent axiom A, ZC+A has lower consistency strength than ZFC+A, but this need not apply to schemas.  For example, Vopěnka's principle over ZC (or just BZC) implies ZFC.

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot to dig into in this answer -- it really seems to cover all the bases! One lingering question -- for a large cardinal property $A(\kappa)$, $ZFC+\exists\kappa A(\kappa)$ typically proves that $V_\kappa$ models $ZFC+\exists \lambda B(\lambda)$ for certain weaker large cardinal properties $B$. And in your answer, you say that $ZF+\exists \kappa A(\kappa)$ typically proves that $V_\kappa$ models $ZFC+\exists \lambda C(\lambda)$ for certain weaker large cardinal properties $C$. Should I be thinking that $B = C$? Or is there rather sometimes a drop in strength from $B$ to $C$?

Comment: @TimCampion There is always a drop in strength, though it typically manifests only with contrived $B$.  However, when the axiom is not $Σ_2$, there are natural examples: For example, ZC + "$κ$ is strong" does not prove that there is a $λ^{+ω}$-strong $λ$ in $V_κ$.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple example of a large cardinal axiom that extends $\sf ZC$ and is stronger than $\sf ZFC$ and yet it can violate $\sf ZFC$. Take for example the theory with the following axioms:

1. **Universes:** every set belongs to a Grothendieck universe.
2. **Denumerability:** No Grothendieck universe can have more than finitely many Grothendieck universes inside it
3. **Separation:** as in $\sf ZC$.

Where a Grothendieck universe can be defined as an extensional well founded transitive set that is closed under powerset, set unions and not-greater in cardinality than operators.

This theory clearly violates $\sf ZFC$, yet it does interpret $\sf ZFC$, and even some versions of $\sf MK$

By the way the wholeness axiom can be considered as an extension of $\sf ZC$, since it doesn't really extend $\sf ZFC$ for all formulas of its language!

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'm missing something obvious -- in what sense does this theory "violate" ZFC? I think I believe that the theory neither extends nor is extended by ZFC in the strict sense -- i.e. it proves things that ZFC does not prove, and vice versa. But if I understand correctly, one can add the scheme of replacement to this theory to arrive at an extension of ZFC which is consistent (provably relative to large cardinals). So I take it you _don't_ mean that adding replacement to this theory results in inconsistency -- right?

Comment: this theory falsifies repalcement, since obviousely you cannot have a set of all Grothendieck unvierses here, but we only have countably many of those? If you add replacement to this theory, it becomes inconsistent!

Comment: @TimCampion (2) violates replacement since under replacement, we could take the supremum of the first $\omega$ inaccessibles.

Comment: Ah right -- I failed to read properly. Of course if you say every set is contained in a universe, but there's only a set of universes, you've left ZFC-land. Cool!

Comment: What is the correct way to define "inaccessible cardinal" in ZC? Does one say that $\kappa$ is inaccessible if $V_\kappa$ is a universe in the sense specified by Zuhair Al-Johar in this answer?

Comment: @TimCampion, as far as I know, ZC is a very able theory as regards defining relations, It does capture the notion of a relation, and of cardinality very well, so I don't see why should it differ from the usual one.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar The last sentence of your answer is very interesting -- as I understand it, the wholeness axiom is an extremely strong large cardinal axiom in $ZFC$, comparable to the $I_n$'s. Do you happen to know anything about its consistency strength as an axiom in $ZC$?

Comment: Sorry -- one other question -- I don't think one can construct Mostowki collapses in $ZC$. So could you say something about the fact that your universes are defined to be transitive rather than just well-founded?

Comment: @TimCampion, actually this is not my personal argument, it is due to Forster and Randall. My personal view about it is that the wholeness axiom uses the FULL instanes of separation, i.e. there is no restriction on the kind of formulas used in separation, so it is a genuine extension of ZC, but it is not of ZFC, because it restrict Replacement. It is inconsistent with full replacement.

Comment: @TimCampion, well I defined them to be BOTH transitive and well founded, this is done by stipulation. I'm not sure of Mostowski's collapses, but I think in the above system I defined one can do it locally inside the universes, however, you need a more qualified opnion than mine on that.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Thanks, this is very illuminating. I just realized that $ZC$ presumably doesn't prove that every set has a rank (even when it includes foundation as I intend it to here). Overall, I'm thinking that passing from $ZFC$ to $ZC$ must be much more complicated than I initially appreciated.

Comment: @TimCampion, there are formulations of $ZC + rank$, Randall Holmes had spoken about this, and I think possibly Scott-Potter also alluded to that. You can easily have extensions of $ZC+rank$ that violate $ZFC$ and yet interpret it also.